# Securing C# TcpClient Operation

Tags: c#, .net, security, tcp

I have a couple of questions about C#.NET client/server applications that communicate via Tcp.

1. How can I best secure my Tcp listener from buffer overflow attacks?  I would imagine it occurs at the point at which I read a line off the StreamReader that is associated with the given TcpClient's NetworkStream, but I don't know specifics.
2. Would someone point me to a really good TcpClient .NET with SSL (via SslStream I guess) tutorial or document?

Thanks guys.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is buffer overflow/overrun possible in completely managed asp.net c# web application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156445/is-buffer-overflow-overrun-possible-in-completely-managed-asp-net-c-sharp-web-ap)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252365/creating-a-tcp-client-connection-with-ssl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. .NET throws exceptions if you try to write outside buffers.
2. That's a very broad question. You'll just wrap the NetworkStream with a SslStream and authenticate as a client or server.

Example:

```
var secureStream = new SslStream(tcpClient.GetStream());
```

MSDN has an example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream.aspx).

Comment: Are the build in .NET defenses reliable and consistent?  I have noticed some parts of the framework that are buggy and I'd hate to put faith in something that isn't bulletproof.

Comment: We either trust .NET or we don't. I wouldn't go adding a lot of extra checks just to safe.